# add attribute to anchor tag in tinymce

Tags: tinymce

I want to add an attribute to the anchor tag through tinymce

The current text I have is

```
<p><a id="1212" title="abc" href="../abc" target="_blank">Test</a></p>
```

Required output is

```
<p><a id="1212" title="abc" href="../abc" sampletest="true" target="_blank">Test</a></p>
```

I just want to add an attribute sampletest="true" to the existing anchor tag

The following will add a class, but I want to add an attribute as above required output.

```
$scope.tinymceOptions.style_formats = [
{ title: 'test', selector : 'a', classes: 'sampletest'}
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
tinyMCE.dom.setAttrib('Element', 'String', 'String');
```

Here,

**Element**: DOM element, element id string or array of elements/ids to set                             attribute on.

**String** :Name of attribute to set.

**String**: Value to set on the attribute of this value is falsy like null 0 or '' it will remove the attribute instead.

For example:

```
// Sets an attribute to all paragraphs in the active editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.setAttrib(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('p'), 'class', 'myclass');

// Sets an attribute to a specific element in the current page
tinyMCE.dom.setAttrib('mydiv', 'class', 'myclass');
```

Comment: where should i add this snippet? after `init` tinymce ?

Comment: This doesn't trigger the change event